# Radial velocity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

I need to calculate the radial velocity ($v_r$) of an object to another. For this I have the cartesian coordinates ($X_n$,$Y_n$,$Z_n$) and cartesian velocities, ($\dot{X_n}$,$\dot{Y_n}$,$\dot{Z_n}$) (with n = (1,2) depending on which object it is). The final result should be in three dimensions, but first I am trying to get this working in one and two dimensions:

For **1D** it is simple: $v_r$=$\dot{X_1}-\dot{X_2}$. There is no angle between the two velocity vectors, and the velocity can be negative too.

For **2D** it is somewhat more difficult, due to the angle between the objects. This angle $\theta$ is $\arctan{\frac{Y_1-Y_2}{X_1-Y_2}}$. One should also keep track in which quadrant it is, as $\arctan()$ only returns values between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ and the angle is obviously between $0$ and $2\pi$. I think the radial velocity is now best calculated in two steps: calculate the x and y components, and then add them by using Pythagoras.

$$
{v_r}_X = (\dot{X_1}-\dot{X_2})\cos{\theta} \\
{v_r}_Y = (\dot{Y_1}-\dot{Y_2})\sin{\theta} 
$$

Is it correct so far? In the obvious cases ($\theta = \frac{k}{2}\pi$, with $k$ a positive integer) this is correct, but I am unsure about the non-obvious cases.

Then comes the **3D** part. This part bothers me the most (unless I am wrong in the 1D or 2D part, then I just fail :P). Now there is another angle, $\phi$. $\theta$ is calculated in the same way as before because it haves no $Z$ component, and $\phi$ is calculated like this:

$$
\phi = \arcsin{(\frac{(Z_1-Z_2)}{\sqrt{(X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-Y_2)^2+(Z_1-Z_2)^2}})}
$$

This angle is always between $-\frac{1}{2}\pi$ and $\frac{1}{2}\pi$. Therefor one should look at $(Z_1-Z_2)$. If that is positive or negative, $\phi$ is positive or negative, respectively.

Very naively I am trying something like:

$$
{v_r}_X = (\dot{X_1}-\dot{X_2})\cos{\theta}\cos{\phi} \\
{v_r}_Y = (\dot{Y_1}-\dot{Y_2})\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi} \\
{v_r}_Z = (\dot{Z_1}-\dot{Z_2})\sin{\phi}
$$

After this it is adding with Pythagoras again. Is this somewhere in the neighborhood of correct? I tried again some obvious cases when the sine or cosine become 0 or 1, and then it seems correct. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it complicated. If the objects are at positions $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$, and velocities $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ their relative velocity is $\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1$ and to get the radial velocity (if I understand correctly, the velocity in the direction of their connecting line), you just use dot product to project to this direction:

$$v_{radial}=(\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1)\cdot\frac{\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1}{|\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1|}$$

If you want the *transverse* velocity (tangential or whatever you call it), you can now get its magnitude from $|\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1|^2=v_{radial}^2+v_{tangential}^2$.

---

The dot product is of course $(x,y,z)\cdot(a,b,c)=ax+by+cz$. The absolute value introduces some square roots into the equation.

---

Edit: this is the *magnitude* of the velocity. If you need a vector, just multiply by the direction again:
$$\vec{v}_{radial}=\left((\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1)\cdot\frac{\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1}{|\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1|}\right)\frac{\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1}{|\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1|}$$
$$=\left((\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1)\cdot(\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1)\right)\frac{\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1}{|\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1|^2}$$

This also gets rid of the square root.

Comment: I am only interested in the radial (in the direction of the connecting line indeed) velocity. So I have to convert it to spherical coordinates and then apply your formula?

Comment: No, these are all vector operations, and they are the easiest to work with in cartesian coordinates. Just expand the dot product:
$$v_{radial}=((\dot{X}_2-\dot{X}_1)(X_2-X_1)+(\dot{Y}_2-\dot{Y}_1)(Y_2-Y_1) + (\dot{Z}_2-\dot{Z}_1)(Z_2-Z_1))/\sqrt{(X_2-X_1)^2+(Y_2-Y_1)^2+(Z_2-Z_1)^2)}$$

You can see why vector notation is better.

Comment: See the edit if you want a vector instead of velocity size.

Comment: Its actually a lot simpler then I thought from the beginning. I was confused by the velocity of object 1 (and the displacement from the origin of object 2), which made me think it was harder then it was. For the record, was it correct what I wrote? It doesn't matter much, but I would like to know if I made an error

Comment: No it was wrong. The step where you introduce the components doesn't do the projection correctly. For instance in 2D, multiplication by sin/cos already projects to the connecting line, so they should be added directly as parallel components, not by pithagoras (which is for perpendicular). Also, if you draw a triangle, you see that $\cos(\arctan(y/x))$ is simply $x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. In 3D it's similar.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks again :)